# Why does using pygame.flip give me a "video system not initialized" error?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to create a window with an image and button in python with pygame. I have written the following code:

```
import pygame as p
import random as r
import time

p.init()
p.font.init()

wind = p.display.set_mode((800, 550), 0, 32)
tus = 1
oooo = p.image.load('oooo.png')



class Button:
    pl = None
    xy = [int, int]
    h = int
    w = int
    text = str
    fonte = str
    font_size = int
    com = None

    def __init__(self, pl,text, x=400, y=525,  bg=(0, 0, 0), fonte='Segoe print', font_size=4, fg=(0, 0, 0)):
        self.bg = bg
        self.pl = pl
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.text = text
        self.fonte = fonte
        self.font_size = font_size
        self.fg = fg
        self.font = p.font.SysFont(fonte, font_size)
        self.reene = self.font.render(text, True, fg, bg)
        self.f = self.pl.blit(self.reene, (self.x, self.y))
    def action(self, com, c_time=0):
        self.ttt = time.sleep(c_time)
        self.com = com
        self.com


def exit():
    p.quit()

while True:
    wind.blit(oooo, (0, 0))
    b_exit = Button(wind, '...EXIT...', bg=(0, 255, 0), fg=(170, 248, 7))
    b_exit.action(exit, c_time=2.75)
    title = p.display.set_caption('cat & mouse & dog')
    for event in p.event.get():
        if event.type == p.QUIT:
           p.quit()
    p.display.flip()
```

This code produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sony/Desktop/sheep/venv/Lib/site-packages/pygame/wrong.py", line 119, in <module>
    p.display.flip()
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you initialise the video system?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the button action is to close the screen, you call the button action with `b_exit.action(exit, c_time=2.75)` every frame, meaning you quit on the first frame. so by the time it gets to update the display, you have already quit. To fix, you want to check if you have clicked the button, then call the button action.
I would start by creating a draw function, and get the width and height of the button, then you can do

```
mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
if mouse_x > b_exit.x and mouse_x < b_exit.x + b_exit.w:
    if mouse.y > b_exit.y and mouse_y < b_exit.y + b_exit.h:
        if button_clicked:
            b_exit.action(exit, c_time=2.75)
```

you also don't need to create an instance of the button class every frame, so move it out of the loop